# Execute task when tab or enter is pressed on a form input text with Backbone/Marionette?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

Is there a way I can execute my method when someone finishes adding/editing data on an input text and presses enter or tab in Backbone?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: You can listen to the submit event in a form view which is triggered when the enter button is pressed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example of how to implement an event upon hitting return in a text field:

```
var SearchView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#template",
    events: {
      'keypress #search-input' : 'searchKeywords',
    },
    searchKeywords: function(e){
      if ( e.which === 13 ) { 
        var keywords = $(e.target).val();

        if(keywords === '') return;

        this.model.set({keywords: keywords});
      }
    }
});
```

The event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode.

http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to `keyup`, `keypress` events and compare `keyCode` property of the event to `13`.
When user navigates form fields by pressing tab key the events are `focus`, `focusin` and `focusout`

Binding to these events should be created as usual with `events` dictionary.

Backbone uses same events as jQuery see [Form Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/form-events/) for more info.